# How to reduce bass levels on microphone

Tags: windows-10, microphone, voip, equalizer

Since my webcam microphone has an echo which makes it difficult for others to understand me when I use it for calling people, I want to reduce the bass level for the microphone since I think it might reduce the echo quite well.

However, when I looked for equalizers, I only found a way to reduce bass levels for my speakers, but not for my mic. How can I do that?

Comment: The echo will be their signal from your speakers returning through your microphone to their system. The way to break that is use headphones, or an array mic. Most of the echoed signal will be in the mid-range, right where voice, mic & speakers are most prevalent.

Comment: No, it's another echo, and it's a very deep sound as well. I have it also when I just record my voice alone. It's because the room has bad acoustics.

Comment: OK, then [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) might do it.I can't test, Im not on Windows.

Comment: I tested it, did not work, sorry - the mic did not work anymore after I tried to optimize it